# gtsummary R package: pre-post summary table with paired 2-sample tests?

Tags: r, gtsummary

Is it possible to use the gtsummary R package to make a pre-post summary table with 2 columns that summarize multiple variables at 2 different time points?

I know the [arsenal R package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/arsenal/index.html) supports this, but I would prefer to use gtsummary if possible since it supports the tidyverse.

For example, is it possible to make a pre-post summary table using gtsummary that is similar to the table in this [example](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/arsenal/vignettes/paired.html)?  Here is a simpler version of the dataset from their example:

```
 dat <- data.frame(
  tp = paste0("Time Point ", c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2)),
  id = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6),
  Cat = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "A", NA, "B"),
  Fac = factor(c("A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A")),
  Num = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 3, 4, 0, NA),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Note the dataset is in "long format": `tp` is the 2 pre-post time points, and `id` is the subject ID for the 2 repeated measures.   To make the table, `Cat` and `Fac` are categorical variables that would be summarized as count(%) at each time point, and use McNemar's test to compare if they change over time.  `Num` is a numeric variable that would be summarized as mean(standard deviation) at each time point, and use paired t-test to assess change over time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, as of gtsummary v1.3.6, there is a function called `add_difference()` for this express purpose. The function supports both paired (e.g. pre- and post-responses), and unpaired data. The method is specified in the `test=` argument.

Worked example here: http://www.danieldsjoberg.com/gtsummary/articles/gallery.html#paired-test

Here's an unpaired example:

```r
  trial %>%
  select(trt, age, marker, response, death) %>%
  tbl_summary(
    by = trt,
    statistic =
      list(
        all_continuous() ~ "{mean} ({sd})",
        all_dichotomous() ~ "{p}%"
      ),
    missing = "no"
  ) %>%
  add_n() %>%
  add_difference()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Daniel.  I also do not understand the "Difference" column in their example.  When I use the arsenal R package to make pre-post summary tables, I always remove this column.

Comment: Not sure what is going on with the categorical data, but for continuous data, "difference" supports case where the difference between the medians is not the median of the differences. For example, if the values at time point A are 1, 2, and 10 and the corresponding values at time point B are 1,12,10, the median at tp A is 2, median at time point B is 10 but the median change from A to B is 0 (median of 1-1, 12-2, and 10-10)